# Override acceptable element content when element context changes

Tags: xml, xsd

### Background

Looking to define the same type of XML element, but in one context as a definition and in the other as a reference. This might be a situation for `key` and `keyref`.

### Problem

Consider the following XML:

```
<recipe>
<equipment>
  <bakeware>
    <object id="1">pan</object>
  </bakeware>
  <cookware>
    <object id="2">pot</object>
  </cookware>
</equipment>

<directions label="dough">
  <step action="roll" time="3">dough on <object id="1" /> until thin</step>
</directions>
</recipe>
```

Within any sub-element of the `equipment` element, the `object` element must have both an `id` and a text value. Within any `step` element, the `object` element can appear, but its `id` attribute must reference an existing `object`, and it may not include a text node.

The way I'm approaching this problem is by creating two definitions for `object`: (1) `objectType`; and (2) `objectDefType`. This might be an error (it seems like inheritance should be possible).

Here is what I have so far:

```
  <xsd:simpleType name="rString">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:normalizedString">
      <xsd:minLength value="1" />
      <xsd:maxLength value="64" />
      <xsd:whiteSpace value="collapse" />
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>

  <xsd:complexType name="objectDefType">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
      <xsd:extension base="rString">
        <xsd:attribute name="id" type="rId" use="required" />
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

I would like to override the `minLength` and `maxLength` elements as follows:

```
  <xsd:complexType name="objectType">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
      <xsd:extension base="rString">
        <xsd:attribute name="id" type="rId" use="required" />

        <xsd:minLength value="0" />
        <xsd:maxLength value="0" />
      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

This results in an error:

> The content is not valid. Expected is (annotation?, ((attribute | attributeGroup)*, anyAttribute?)).

I have tried several ways to define this item, including changing it to a `complexContent`, but each attempt has resulted in a different error.

### Question

What is the XSD to define an object using `<object id="1">pan</object>` and refer to it by its key `<object id="1" />`, elsewhere in the document?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your XSD error, this is how the corrected definition would look like - it basically defines an element with emtpy content.

```
<xsd:complexType name="objectType">
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="rId" use="required"/>
</xsd:complexType>
```

This is the only way, actually. Trying other combinations that would work from a structure perspective (have objectType restrict objectDefType), would not work from a "derived" facet's value perspective: can't have them less than the value of the parent.

As for the other part, I'll try to explain my thought process, to allow you to improve it based on your particular contraints.

I've started by taking your XML and generate a dummy XSD from it. Here is what it came up with, and it works (it validates the particular XML instance):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="recipe">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="equipment">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="bakeware">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="object">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                          <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
                          </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="cookware">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="object">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:simpleContent>
                          <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
                          </xs:extension>
                        </xs:simpleContent>
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="directions">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="step">
                <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="object">
                      <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
                      </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute name="action" type="xs:string" use="required" />
                  <xs:attribute name="time" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="label" type="xs:string" use="required" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

From this, first thing you'll notice is that with this authoring style, referred to as Russian Doll since everything is nested, you'll have two local, hence completely independent, definitions for the object tag. This could then be the basis for your solution, depending now on what and how would you like to reuse XSD content.

The easiest way then to have "context" is to make the element local to your context. To reuse parts, one way might be to either make the id attribute and/or its type global. Or point back to the complex types discussion above.

Hope it helps...